# Do Azure audit logs contain Internal API

Tags: azure, auditing

External API are the ones which are published in the azure documentation and used by system integrators to develop Azure solutions

Internal API are the ones which are not published and internally called by Azure to accomplish something.

Question is:

1. Does Azure audit log contain audit of internal API?
2. Does a API auditing for a SaaS solution should audit External API only or it should audit Internal APIs as well?

Searching in Stack Overflow
Searching in Azure documentation